# Elegant Kotlin Object Enriching

Tags: kotlin

I would like to output an object based upon an input object. I want to enrich it by populating an empty array contained within the input object. The new array is based on an existing array contained in the object. The output object is deep equal to the input object except it contains the new array. I have developed the following code block:

```kotlin
fun enrich(a: T1) {
    val b = mutableListOf<T1>()
    a.forEach { it1 ->
        val bb = mutableListOf<T2>()
        it1.aa.forEach { it2 ->
            val bbb = mutableListOf<T3>()
            it2.aaa.forEach { it3 ->
                bbb.add(T3("somevalue based upon it3"))
            }
            bb.add(T2(bbb))
        }
        b.add(T1(aa, bb))
    }
    return b
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` method. So the final solution may look like this

```
fun enrich(a: MutableList<T1>): MutableList<T1> {
    return a.map { it1 ->
        T1(it1.aa.map { it2 ->
            T2(it2.aaa.map { it3 ->
                T3("somevalue based upon $it3")
            })
        })
    }.toMutableList()
}
```

Comment: Also, I think I'd make it an extension function (`fun MutableList<T1>.enriched(): MutableList<T1>`).  (The past participle ‘enriched’ implies that it returns a new object — without mutating the original, which is what the bare verb ‘enrich’ would imply.  Compare [sort()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort.html) and [sorted()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted.html).)